# Solve for $f(x)$ and for $n$ related to consecutive derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Seeing that the sine derivative returns to be the same function every $4$ derivatives, it occurred to me to ask myself the following 2 problems

> Statement 1: Get all the functions such that $\large{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f } =f(x),$ with $n = 4$

For this statement i know that for $f(x) = \sin x$ holds, but how i can get others functions that holds? Is there a theorem related to this? And what about of the functions for other values of $n$ ?

> Analogous statement 2: If is possible, get $n$ such that $\large{ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f = f(x)}$ with $f(x) = \sin x$

Obviously, without derivative consecutively and for other possible functions.

So, are some theorems or ways to solving these problems?

Comment: The function is does not have a $+c$.

Comment: @SamuelA.Morales It should be multiplied by a $c\in \mathbb{R}$, though.

Comment: @SamuelA.Morales, yes, was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is just solving a fourth order ODE:
$$y^{[4]}(x)-y(x)=0$$
We guess a solution of the form $y(x)=Ce^{rx}$:
$$Cr^4e^{rx}-Ce^{rx}=0$$
$$r^4=1$$
We are looking for the fourth roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}.$ They are $1,-1,i$, and $-i$. Therefore a general solution is a linear combination of these four linearly independent solutions.
$$y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+c_3e^{ix}+c_4e^{-ix}$$

Now we use Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$:
$$y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+c_3(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))+c_4(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))$$
In order for $y$ to be real valued, it must be the case that $c_4={c_3}^*$. Let $c_3=\frac{a}{2}+i\frac{b}{2}$. Then,
$$y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+a\cos(x)-b\sin(x)$$
Renaming our variables,
$$y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+C\sin(x)+D\cos(x)$$
@Samuel A. Morales did mention that these four fundamental solutions are the only *linearly independent* solutions that exist to these fourth order ODE, but any *linear combination* of these four fundamental solutions will also have the property you seek. It's also fairly easy to see how this generalizes to higher derivatives.

Comment: why you suppose a solution of that form?

Comment: @Eduardo S. Well it worked didn't it? I found four linearly independent solutions. Since this is a fourth order ODE, there cannot be any others.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how in order for this to work the derivatives must belong to a cycle, from my knowledge the only ones that do this are:

$$f(x)=e^x\\
j(x)=e^{-x}\\
g(x)=\sin(x)\\
h(x)=\cos(x)$$

I do not know any theorem regarding this, I came up with the solutions using intuition, such as noting that $x^\alpha$ will not work, neither any $\log_\alpha{x}$, nor $\alpha^x$

Comment: what about a combination of these functions?

Comment: You are totally right, this makes the question have infinetly many solutions